# Access Input Control

Tags: x11, gui, libraries, c++

I am currently trying to get into writing something like an autoclicker. I work on a openSUSE Leap with KDE environment and program in c++ or FORTRAN or python.

In order to do so I need access to whatever interface there is between the gui and the computer.

I first was inclined to use  Xlib and Xutil which are apparently libraries that give access  to  the I/O functions of the GUI, but they don't come preinstalled with this system.

Now first I thought about installing them, but then I thought I would rather like to know what makes them, what is that invisible layer between my c++ code and the rest of the computer.

I am really out of my depths here, which is why my question might be formulated in an obscure way, but I thought, maybe I try and change that.

Would appreciate recommendations.

Cheers.

Comment: Start by reading about the [`XTest`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXtst/xtestlib.html) library/extension, which allows you to generate clicks, keypresses and other input events just as if they came from a real keyboard or mouse. There's the `xdotool` program which is using it, and despite being buggy, awkward and limited, can be used for simple "autoclick" tasks. Or, at a lower level, the [`uinput`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html) Linux module. Creating a robust expect-like framework for instrumenting GUIs would be a lot of work, though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I pasted together a testcode fur uinput usage from [uinput](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html)  and [epitron/uinput-sample.c](https://gist.github.com/epitron/6760108) which results in ``error: open: Permission denied". I reckon I'm doing something wrong as any new USB is mounted without the necessity of root privileges.

Comment: No, you cannot use `uinput` without root privileges. But any client with full  access to an X11 display can use `XTest` (full access means local client or ssh + ForwardX11Trusted).

Comment: Here is what I don't get. I can download something like  [maxautoclicker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxautoclicker/) and it will run as advertised without me having any root privileges at the time of unpacking the download.  It doesn't ask for specific prerequisites like  libxtst or XTest it just runs. How does it do that?

Comment: That program you link to is using the `XTest` library/extension I was talking about.

Comment: `ldd ... | grep libXtst`.

Comment: Now in order to complete the answer somewhat: From what I can tell it seems like there are libraries, like XTest, that allow access to functions of kernel modules like uinput which one can not access without root privileges. These kernel modules spawn into existence at installation time and are therefor always introduced by root. The only remaining question is then, how do you write a kernel module. If this is it I consider my question answered.

Comment: No, the `XTest` library doesn't make use of `uinput` or other kernel functions, and doesn't escalate the privileges of the program which is using it. That library is a (very simple) wrapper which allows one to use the `XTEST` extension of the X11 server, which in turn works by creating a virtual mouse and  keyboard accessible only to the X11 server (`xinput` will show you those virtual devices). The problem with `XTest` is that it only works with X11 applications, not with native wayland applications.